# graphhopper reverse route not found

Tags: routes, reverse, graphhopper

I'd like to get a matrix of road distances and travel times between multiple points.
I have an issue between these to points:-

51.081297772562586,-4.06079346786545 and 51.54113829438801,-0.0005337596804528456

Grpahhopper can find a route from A to B but not B to A.

another example is for these points

51.0813193,-4.0607013 and 51.5416019,-0.0004748

I've tried adjusting "prepare.minOnewayNetworkSize" and all sorts of combinations of Ch and algorithms.

I've also tried using mapquest, it fails on exactly the same routes with a status of 602 ("Route matrix failed - unknown error in route computation")

http://open.mapquestapi.com/directions/v2/routeMatrix?key=MY_KEY&from=51.5416019,-0.0004748&to=51.0813193,-4.0607013&narrativeType=none

Is there a problem with the osm data, my configuration or my understanding of the problem?

other routes are working fine

Answer (score 0):

It should definitely find a route as you can see at [GraphHopper Maps](https://graphhopper.com/maps/?point=51.081278%2C-4.060875&point=51.541138%2C-0.000534&layer=Lyrk). My guess is that you have to try the minOnewayNetworkSize again and make sure that for this route that the destination can be reached (looks like a 'oneway trap').